# Como encontrar palavras especificas em um arquivo txt em python?

Tags: python, txt

Preciso fazer um software que procure por palavras no código e guarde em uma string a próxima linha.
Não achei nada de como fazer isso em nenhum lugar, Só achei um que conta o número de palavras no arquivo como esse

```
with open('File_of_data.txt', 'r',encoding='utf8') as j:
    for line in j:
        words = line.split('\n')
        num_lines += 1
        num_words += len(words)
print(num_lines)
print(num_words)
```

Após encontrar a palavra como o nome de uma pessoa "Carlos" na linha de baixo vai estar as informações dessa pessoa e preciso guardar isso para fazer cálculos.

Comment: Vou aderir as dicas :D valeu

Comment: Não seria melhor ler tudo isso para um dicionário em memoria em que as chaves são os nomes das pessoas?

Comment: Você pode resolver esse problema com uma máquina de estados. Mas sem uma amostra do arquivo de entrada, fica complicado te ajudar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode construir uma simples máquina de estados que realiza uma busca linha por linha de um dado arquivo de entrada, buscando pelo nome ou um dos sobrenomes da pessoa.

Ao encontrar uma pessoa compatível com a pesquisa, a máquina de estados assume que a próxima linha a ser lida contém os dados dessa pessoa.

Uma vez com a linha contendo os dados da pessoa encontrada, um dicionário pode ser montado e retornado para uso geral:

```
def pesquisar_registro( arq, txt ):
    nome = ""
    with open( arq, 'r' ) as a:
        for linha in a:
            linha = linha.strip('\n')
            if nome == "":
                if txt in linha.split():
                    nome = linha
            else:
                registro = linha.split(',')
                dic = { "nome"       : nome,         \
                        "cod"        : registro[0],  \
                        "pais_nasc"  : registro[1],  \
                        "ano_nasc"   : registro[2],  \
                        "pais_morte" : registro[3],  \
                        "ano_morte"  : registro[4] }
                return dic;
    return None;


print pesquisar_registro( 'fisicos.txt', 'Einstein' )
print pesquisar_registro( 'fisicos.txt', 'Max' )
print pesquisar_registro( 'fisicos.txt', 'Michael' )
print pesquisar_registro( 'fisicos.txt', 'Curie' )
print pesquisar_registro( 'fisicos.txt', 'Obama' )
```

**fisicos.txt**

```
Albert Einstein
100,Alemanha,1879,EUA,1955
Isaac Newton
200,Reino Unido,1643,Reino Unido,1727
Galileo Galilei
300,Italia,1564,Italia,1642
Marie Curie
400,Polonia,1867,Polonia,1934
Erwin Schrodinger
500,Austia,1887,Austria,1961
Michael Faraday
600,Reino Unido,1791,Reino Unido,1867
Max Planck
700,Alemanha,1858,Alemanha,1947
```

Saída:

```
{'ano_nasc': '1879', 'pais_nasc': 'Alemanha', 'nome': 'Albert Einstein', 'ano_morte': '1955', 'cod': '100', 'pais_morte': 'EUA'}
{'ano_nasc': '1858', 'pais_nasc': 'Alemanha', 'nome': 'Max Planck', 'ano_morte': '1947', 'cod': '700', 'pais_morte': 'Alemanha'}
{'ano_nasc': '1791', 'pais_nasc': 'Reino Unido', 'nome': 'Michael Faraday', 'ano_morte': '1867', 'cod': '600', 'pais_morte': 'Reino Unido'}
{'ano_nasc': '1867', 'pais_nasc': 'Polonia', 'nome': 'Marie Curie', 'ano_morte': '1934', 'cod': '400', 'pais_morte': 'Polonia'}
None
```

Answer (score 2):

Primeiramente obrigado Lacobus. Bom eu necessitei de algo parecido, mas armazenado de forma diferente. Deixo aqui o codigo adaptado por mim.

Codigo:

```
def pesquisar_registro( txt, posicao ):
resultado = ""
with open( 'arquivo.txt', 'r' ) as a:
    for linha in a:
        if resultado == "":
            if txt in linha:
                resultado = linha
                res = resultado.split('= ')[posicao].strip('\n')
                return res;
    else: a.close()
return None;


print pesquisar_registro( 'modelo', 1 ) # Nome da variavel e posição do resultado dsp do '='
```

arquivo.txt

```
marca= Fiat 
modelo= Argo
ano= 2019
placa= AAA-0000
cor= Vermelho
```

Saida:

```
Argo
```